# If Windows explorer is open at a specific path, do not create a new instance

Tags: c#, process, windows-explorer

I am using the following code so that when the user clicks on a button, an instance of *Windows Explorer* is opened at a specific path. But this causes a new instance of the *Explorer* to be opened.

I want to change it so that, if *Explorer* is already open in the same path, the program does not create a new process and instead bring the open instance to front.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(myPath))
        Process filesFolder =  Process.Start("explorer.exe", Conf.FilesLocation);               
}
```

Comment: Then  *don't start* a new instance, find the existing one's window and bring it to the foreground

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's the question. How do I know if it's already open or not?

Comment: @disasterkid, see my answer to know if it's already open or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "open" verb, which will open directories in explorer and re-use an an existing explorer.exe if you pass it a directory that it already has open:
So, assuming `Conf.FilesLocation` is a directory:

```
        var proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        proc.FileName = Conf.FilesLocation;
        proc.Verb = "open";
        proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process.Start(proc );
```

Comment: The line with `proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` causes this to fail opening explorer.exe, must be removed.

Answer (score 3):

What I have found to work as well, is to use the `file://` protocol, when you do this Windows seems to give focus to the folder if it is already open, rather than opening another window

```
Process.Start("file://" + Conf.FilesLocation);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although @nos's answer works well, mostly (sometimes, in a not deterministically way it creates another explorer windows even though it may already exists), I became unsatisfied with the time spent by the `Process.Start(proc)` to open an existing window, sometimes 2 to 4 seconds.

So, adapting some [VB.NET code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511454/get-path-that-file-explorer-is-displaying-using-its-window-handle) I achieve a very fast way of reusing a existing explorer window that is pointing to a desired folder:

First, add COM references:

`using Shell32;//Shell32.dll for ShellFolderView`

`using SHDocVw;//Microsoft Internet Controls for IShellWindows`

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr Hwnd, int iCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr Hwnd);

    public static bool ShowInExplorer(string folderName) 
    {
        var SW_RESTORE = 9;
        var exShell = (IShellDispatch2)Activator.CreateInstance(                                           
                            Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));
        
        foreach (ShellBrowserWindow w in (IShellWindows) exShell.Windows())
        {
              

            if (w.Document is ShellFolderView)
                {
                    var expPath = w.Document.FocusedItem.Path;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(expPath)) ||
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(expPath) != folderName) continue;
                    if (IsIconic(new IntPtr(w.HWND)))
                    {
                        w.Visible = false;
                        w.Visible = true;
                        ShowWindow(new IntPtr(w.HWND),SW_RESTORE);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        w.Visible = false;
                        w.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
         }
    }
```

Although we are interested in ShellFolderView objects, and `foreach (ShellBrowserWindow w in (ShellFolderView) exShell.Windows())` was more *logical*, unfortunately ShellFolderView does not implement IEnumerable, so, no foreach :(

Anyway, these is a very fast (200 ms) way of select and blink the correct already opened explorer window.

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the solutions here work in Win10. For Marcelo's solution `exShell.Windows()` is always empty, Josh's solution doesn't work for directories, you'll get `file does not exist` error, and nos' solution throws `access denied` error.

So here's my working solution:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr Hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    public static void ShowInExplorer(string filePath) {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("CabinetWClass", Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        } else {
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        }
    }
```

Windows Explorer has window class `CabinetWClass` and sets title to the browsed directory.

So the above code checks to see if an explorer window with a specific directory exists.

If it does exist, the window is brought to the front, otherwise a new instance of explorer is started with the specified directory. Do note that you need to specifically start `explorer.exe` with the path given as argument, otherwise it'll throw `access denied` error.

Comment: This solution worked wonder for me. Also, I don't know to which extend, but there could be another type of window class name `Explorer­WClass` according to this blog post, but that is just for old windows versions:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150619-00/?p=45341
Still this is the most simple working solution I found