# Is there a way to obtain IExplorerBrowser interface of running or newly open explorer window for subsequent BrowseToXXX call?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, shell, language-agnostic

Asking because in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220899/#answer-6221898) i was pointer to IExplorerBrowser, however it creates a child window, while Explorer's "Find Target..."behaviour i want to simulate (see [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220899/)) exhibits some level of control over newly open or existing Explorer window (i believe that right term is folder view, feel free to correct). Also looking for other API(s) to accomplish BrowsingTo or similar behaviour.

Comment: Downvoter, step into the light!

Comment: +1 for `step into the light` Didn't downvote, but I had to reread your question 3x before I got it. Your habit of not stating the full question in the box, but combining the heading and the text as one flowing/confusing question doesn't help. The shortness of the question doesn't help either.

Comment: @user759588 - I'm the downvoter and I hope you know why. Your questions are really confusing me. The question you've posted before is still the real puzzle for the people who didn't concerned about that and I really have no idea what means `IExplorerBrowser embeds as child window, also looking for other interface(s) to accomplish BrowsingTo` in this question, sorry that I can't mention in the comment but I've had a long internet break in our company. Also you were quite offensive with the thought your previous question is clear for everyone and it seems you are doing the same with this one.

Comment: @user759588 - about `step into the light` - you'll might to step `into yourself` before `step into the light`.

Comment: @user And seeing the revision of the post, why do you tag it language agnostic AND c++ AND delphi? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RedX, these specific languages are preferred for code-snippet type of answer, but not required, as i'm seeking the right APIs. Also, both [c++] and [delphi] being attended by Win32 programmers

Comment: I answered for your previous question, so I think you have no need in IExplorerBrowser interface anymore

Comment: @Anton Semenov, yes, i found your answer, thanks again. As side interest: how did you find it? Asking because sometimes i'm having trouble getting the right audience for my Win32 specific questions.

Comment: @user759588: I opened this function for myself several years ago. Today, when I read this question I just remembered that the function has 'SH' prefix, so I opened shell functions list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776426%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and after minute or two of searching found it. So after that, i just enter `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` in search box in this site and found appropriate post

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. See Raymond Chen's [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110325-00/?p=11133) on the subject.

> Aha, the program is using Explorer as a “view this folder for a little while” subroutine. Unfortunately, Explorer doesn’t work that way. For example, the user might decide to use the Address Bar and go visit some other folders completely unrelated to your program, and your program would just be sitting there waiting for the user to close that window; meanwhile, the user doesn’t realize that your program is waiting for it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226883/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-iexplorerbrowser-interface-of-running-or-newly-open-expl/6232916#6232916) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220899/how-do-i-display-explorer-with-a-file-selected/6221898#6221898) answers are contradicting to each other, meaning at least one of them is misleading. I appreciate your Google search skills, but cannot welcome such approach when answering specific technical question.