# How can I set an existing Explorer.exe instance to select a file?

Tags: c#

I can easily get Explorer to open up and select a file using the following :

```
string argument = @"/select, " + filePath;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", argument);
```

However when I come to opening up the next file, I will get a new instance of explorer. This could result in our users opening having hundreds of explorers open by the end of an intensive day.

How can I get it to reuse an already open explorer instance to select the file I want?

Visual Studio can do this when you right click on a tab and select *Open containing folder...* providing explorer is already opened at the same directory. How has it been able to do this?

Comment: Why do you have to use explorer in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath)` ?That way you open the file with the assigned default program.

Comment: @ChrisBint Our app has clients. Each client has a folder where their various documents are stored. We want the option to open explorer at the clients folder so they can browse / edit / copy etc... the clients documents.

Comment: Nice, I never noticed that VS will try and reuse the same window. Also, there's nothing wrong with the question as is, opening explorer rather than the file has a lot of uses (hence why it's in VS).

Comment: @Alex, I want to open explorer so the user can browse rather than any particular file..

Comment: This requires Automation support, hard to come by.  There is some left over from the days when they tried to turn the shell into a browser.  ShDocVw.ShellWindows returns a list of both IE and shell windows.  No idea how far you'll get with this or how well this is still supported.

Comment: The right answer is to use SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010305/programmatically-selecting-file-in-explorer/3010871#3010871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [embedding the Explorer window into your application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/25/10145644.aspx) by using the `ExplorerBrowser` object? That way, you can just keep reusing the window by calling [`IExplorerBrowser::BrowseToObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761898.aspx) on a different folder when you want to show a different folder.

Trying to renavigate an existing Explorer window is problematic because you don't know what the user did with that window while you weren't looking. Maybe they used the Folder pane to go to some other folder, and then *boom* you just ripped that folder out from under them and sent it somewhere else. Or maybe they closed it! Opening a new Explorer window is a fire-and-forget type of thing. If you want to retain control of the window, then you need to exercise more explicit control (e.g. via `ExplorerBrowser` above).

Comment: Windows itself uses this behaviour of reusing opened explorer windows. For example selecting a folder and typing Ctrl+Enter to open it in a new window. If you do it again, it does not open a new window instance.

Comment: That's not the same as renavigating an existing window.

Comment: well, then using then contextual menu in a shortcut (Windows 7) and clicking 'find target' or similar (I have spanish version). If the target file is in an open window, Windows reuses it.

Comment: Right, but that is not a renavigate. It's not like it took your My Computer window and changed it to a My Documents window. It just took an existing window that was already open to the correct location.

Comment: Yes, really it's not the same. What I meant is valid only for files in the same location. (btw, I'd like to do this using .NET!)

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but if you want to select one or more files in a folder that already opened in an explorer window, you can do so with the shell32 method `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`. That method re-uses an existing window if there's one, or opens a new one otherwise.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
private static extern int SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(IntPtr pidlFolder, uint cidl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] IntPtr[] apidl, uint dwFlags);

[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
private static extern void SHParseDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string name, IntPtr bindingContext, out IntPtr pidl, uint sfgaoIn, out uint psfgaoOut);

public static void ShowFileInExplorer(string folderPath, string filePath)
{
    Shell32.SHParseDisplayName(Path.GetFullPath(folderPath), IntPtr.Zero, out IntPtr folder, 0, out uint psfgaoOut);

    if (folder == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        return;
    }

    Shell32.SHParseDisplayName(Path.GetFullPath(filePath), IntPtr.Zero, out IntPtr file, 0, out psfgaoOut);

    if (file != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        IntPtr[] files = { file };

        Shell32.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, (uint)files.Length, files, 0);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(file);
    }

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(folder);
}
```

This sample only selects one file, but can easily be extended to select multiple files.

Comment: Thanks @Domi, I've tried this from Java and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting an instance of the `Process` class and always using that to call the `Start()` method?

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
string argument = @"/select, " + filePath;

myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = argument;
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: This works if its the same path as the previous call. Opens a new window on different paths thoug.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), `Start()` will "start (or reuse) the process resource". So that implies that you can change the value of `myProcess.StartInfo.FileName` and call `Start()` again?

Comment: @Widor This is not an answer, rather a question. Without confirming if it works from the answerer, it is a pure speculation.

Comment: Won't work that way. You have to specify the command that has to be executed in `FileName` NOT the argument! The arguments are specified in the `Arguments`-Property.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the Win32 API way.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(@"C:\temp\");
 hWnd = (...) // get Handle of the Explorer's address field.
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, new IntPtr(sb.ToString().Length), sb)
```

`// Set the focus to the address field`

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFOCUS, IntPtr.Zero, null)
// Simulate Enter key
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), null)
```

Comment: There is no portable way of obtaining the address field, and you can't reliably simulate input by sending messages.

Comment: You can enumerate all child windows of the explorer process and by checking the CLASS, find out the address field. Have a look at Spy++.

Comment: Hunting for a specific CLASS is not portable. The class name of the address bar has changed over the years, and it may very well change again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For similar purpose I use launchkey.exe "{F4}^AC:\TEMP{ENTER}" to send F4 key message and direct current explorer instance to c:\TEMP folder.

I run it from right-click shell context menu item:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\85TEMP]
"Position"="Top"
@="JUMP TO TEMP"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\85TEMP\command]
@="c:\\launchkey\\launchkey.exe \"{F4}^AC:\\TEMP{ENTER}\""
```

"JUMP TO TEMP" is displayed item name
"85*" exists to let keep order among other "jumps" which I have several. Items are ordered in reverse by key name, hence number in front.