# Thai combining char

Tags: winapi, windows-7, unicode, windows-vista, thai

Recently I'm dealing with a issue with open Thai named file in folder in development. Usually we do this by:

Java: ProcessBuilder with `"explorer /n,/select,/folder/อักษรไทย.jpg"`
Windows C API: ShellExecuteW with `L"explorer" L"open" L"/n,/select,/folder/อักษรไทย.jpg"`

They all work for WinXP system, but failed for Windows Vista and Windows 7.

And the weird thing is, when I removed the combining char from the filename, they all work fine: from อักษรไทย to อกษรไทย.

I've also tried other UTF8 languages like Chinese and Japanese which are both have no combining characters in their char sets.

Also, the Java awt function `Desktop.open(File) works fine for opening such folders or files with combining Thai characters, but unfortunately, I've not found function like that can select a file in folder.

Do you have any ideas about the difference?

Comment: View binary of the file name. Then, compare it with the binary of the file name that you passed to `ShellExecuteW`. It should not matches. If it matched, that mean this is a bug in Windows Vista/7.

Comment: Thank you for your response. And yes, I've also tried with another API ShellExcecuteExW, and pass the exact Unicode bytes of file name to that param of Win API, still it does not accept combining characters.

Comment: Also, when I tried the "open containing folder" in Firefox's downloads component, and "show in folder" in Chrome's downloads component, they can both open combining path correctly in Win7. And Win7 can open shotcut/link file by "open file location" properly.

Comment: I wonder which APIs do those functions use.

Comment: Try `ShellExecuteW(hWnd, NULL, L"full path of directory to open", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL)`.

Comment: I've tried this way as very first way. It does not work even no "/n,/select" parameter attached.

Comment: Another idea I guess would resolve this is: open the parent folder firstly with Java Desktop.open(File), which is quite easy; and then use some windows MFC handler or some windows API to highlight the file supposed to be chosen. I hope there're some functions that could accept file parameter as a pointer to file instead of a String represent the path or name of that file, in this way, I can pass around the combining character rock.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010305/programmatically-selecting-file-in-explorer what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, it seems that's close to what I want. I wrote a function:      `int BrowseToFile(LPCTSTR filename)  
      {  
        ITEMIDLIST *pidl = ILCreateFromPathW(filename);  
        if(pidl) {  
            int result = SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl,0,0,0);  
            ILFree(pidl);  
      return result;  
        }else  
      return -1;  
    }`    and this returns a value 0x800401F0, which is not even in the `HRESULT` return value list.

Comment: I guess I forgot this: Remarks

CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx must be called before using SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems. Not doing so causes SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems to fail.

Comment: Thank you so much Putta. This function seems work. I'll see how to apply this to my work. Which I want is to select/highligh a file in its parent folder by Windows Explorer. In this case, only Thai combining character(like ◌็
0E47
231  ◌่
0E48
232  ◌้
0E49
233  ◌๊
0E4A
234  ◌๋
0E4B
235  ◌์
0E4C
236  ◌ํ
0E4D
237  ◌๎
0E4E
238) cannot be excepted by normal WinAPI in Win7 or Vista. Now, I hope file pointer parameter function would solve this. Thanks again!

Comment: It resolved my case successfully. Thank you a lot.

Comment: No problem. It's good to see Thai people in stackoverflow. :)