# MFC Open file location and select (highlight) the file

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using this code

```
STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    CString commandLine = _T("explorer.exe ") + CPathName(destination).DirectoryPath();
    CreateProcess(NULL, commandLine.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

to open the location of the exported file. Is there a way that the file can be selected so that I don't have to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is too complex, you can just use

ShellExecute

A bunch of other solutions can be found here:

[Programmatically selecting file in explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010305/programmatically-selecting-file-in-explorer)

Comment: Thank you! I used the winning answer and is working just fine.