# SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems() with arrays

Tags: windows, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I can successfully use `SHOpenFolderandSelectItems()` in trivial cases.  Code looks similar to this:

```
ITEMIDLIST *idl = ILCreateFromPath(L"C:\\testing\\example.txt");
SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(idl, 0, 0, 0);
ILFree(idl);
```

Now what I'd like to do is open up a folder and select multiple files within it.  But I'm confused as to what `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems()` is expecting.  Simplified, this is what I'm trying:

```
ITEMIDLIST *folder = ILCreateFromPath(L"C:\\testing\\");
std::vector<ITEMIDLIST*> v;
v.push_back( ILCreateFromPath(L"C:\\testing\\test1.txt");
v.push_back( ILCreateFromPath(L"C:\\testing\\test2.txt");
v.push_back( ILCreateFromPath(L"C:\\testing\\test3.txt");

SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, v.size(), v.data(), 0);

for (auto idl : v)
{
    ILFree(idl);
}
ILFree(folder);
```

This results in:

```
error C2664: 'HRESULT SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(LPCITEMIDLIST,UINT,LPCITEMIDLIST *,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 3 from '_ITEMIDLIST **' to 'LPCITEMIDLIST *'
```

What is a decent way to create the array of items?

Comment: use `std::vector<LPCITEMIDLIST> v;` or `const_cast<LPCITEMIDLIST*>(v.data())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is only syntax error. you have 2 choice:

1.)

use `std::vector<LPCITEMIDLIST> v;`

in this case you need use **const_cast** when call  `ILFree(const_cast<LPITEMIDLIST>(idl));`

2.)

use `std::vector<LPITEMIDLIST> v;`

in this case you need **const_cast** in call

`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, v.size(), const_cast<LPCITEMIDLIST*>(v.data()), 0);`

however binary code will be absolute the same in both case

Answer (score 1):

Try as shown below (Working):

```
HRESULT hr;
hr = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

ITEMIDLIST *folder = ILCreateFromPath("C:\\testing\\");
std::vector<LPITEMIDLIST> v;
v.push_back(ILCreateFromPath("C:\\testing\\test1.txt"));
v.push_back(ILCreateFromPath("C:\\testing\\test2.txt"));

SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(folder, v.size(), (LPCITEMIDLIST*)v.data(), 0);

for (auto idl : v)
{
    ILFree(idl);
}
ILFree(folder);
```